# A question related to cofinality and cofinal subclass

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

I am confusing about the definition of cofinal subclass and cofinality.To be more precise, I don't understand why there exists some regular ordinals β such that      cf(β)=β. In my understanding way, if I choose the cofinal subclass of β just β for any ordinal β(As β⊆β), then I have cf(β)=1 for any ordinal. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest example is $\omega$.  As $\omega \not \lt \omega$, you can't choose that.  If you choose any finite ordinal it is not cofinal with $\omega$, so you have to choose an infinite subset.  Therefore $cf(\omega)=\omega$.  Your approach works for any successor ordinal, but not limit ones.

Comment: Ross Millikan:So what you mean is we can't choose an ordinal which exactly equals to β.For a limit ordinal β,the only way we can do is choose a class of ordinals which is strictly less than β in order to make sure that the least upper bound of this class is β.Furthermore,the cofinality of β is just simply means that the least number of element that the cofinal subclass of β need to have?

Comment: @AndrewArmstrong:  That is correct.  The class of ordinals has to eventually get greater than any number less than $\beta$.  For example, within $\omega$, you can use any class that gets infinitely large

Comment: Ross Millikan:Now I got it!Thanks!